# Resources about implementing a database table

Tags: data-structures, database-theory, databases

I'd like to understand more how data can be stored on disk so it can be read quickly. I don't want to say database record because I'm not asking how to build a database. My question is closer to how would I build a table.

I'm not asking about indexing. I'm thinking about you have an application that already has some a pointer to a record.

I've been trying to find some references e.g. papers, books, but everything so far focuses on database design as in writing DDL or structures for indexing like B+ trees.

Are there any references that talk about how tables are actually implemented and what are the tradeoffs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases have some issues that "mere mortal" data storage doesn't concern itself with, such as transaction safety and disk failure.

Here are a few classic papers on the topic:

- Astrahan et al (1976), *[System R: A Relational Approach to Data Base Management](https://www.academia.edu/8010241/System_R_A_Relational_Approach_to_Data_Base_Management)*, ACM TOMS 1:2, pp 97-137.
- Stonebreaker et al (1976), *[The Design and Implementation of INGRES](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/cis650/papers/INGRES.PDF)*, ACM TOMS 1:3, pp 189-222.
- Stonebreaker (1987), *[The Design of the POSTGRES Storage System](https://dsf.berkeley.edu/papers/ERL-M87-06.pdf)*, VLDB '87, pp. 289–300.

There are also some good books that cover the relevant topics, such as *[Database System Implementation](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/dbsi.html)* by Garcia-Molina, Ullman, and Widom.